# jQuery event not firing after AJAX load. Need to click twice before event is triggered

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a page, which has a parent form and the child form.

The javascript portion of the parent form:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btnAdd').click(function () {
            var mymodal = $('#attnModal');
            mymodal.find('.modal-title').text("Add Attendance")
            mymodal.find('.modal-body').load('@(Url.Action("NewAttendance", "Attendance"))?sessionN=' + '@Model.Session_N');
        });
    }
</script>
```

It has a button, called `Add Attendance`

```
<button id="btnAdd" type="button" class="btn btn-default" title="Add Attendance" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#attnModal" data-backdrop="false">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
</button>
```

Which when is clicked, it will show the following dialog box

```
<div class="modal fade" id="attnModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content" style="max-width:500px;">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Attendance</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                @*<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>*@
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Inside the `modal-body`, there is a child form. In this form, there is a button AddAttendance, which is an ajax call.
Following is the javascript function.

```
$('#btnAddAttendance').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    ...
    $.ajax({
        ...
        success: function (data) {
            if (!data.Status) {
                OpenAlertPopup("User", "The user id is not valid.")
                return false;
            }
            else {
                $.ajax({
                    ...
                    success: function (res) {
                        if (res.Status) {
                            $('#attnModal').modal().hide();
                            $('#btnReload').click();
                        }
                        else {
                            OpenAlertPopup("Attendance", res.ErrorMessage);
                            $('#attnModal').modal().hide();
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (request, status, error) {
                        alert(error);
                        console.log("ajax call went wrong:" + request.responseText);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

This is the child form.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Add", "Attendance", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frmAdd" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        ...
        <div class="form-group">
            ...
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <input type="button" value="Add" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnAddAttendance"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Following is the sequence:

1. I click `btnAdd`, the dialog `attnModal` will appear.
2. Enter in the data, and click `btnAddAttendance`
3. The system will close `attnModal`, add the data, and reload the attendance list.
4. I click `btnAdd` again, but this time, `attnModal` does not appear.
   There is no console error logged.
   If I click `btnAdd` another time, then the dialog `attnModal` will appear.

How to resolve the issue such that I don't have to click `btnAdd` twice?

Comment: Please only add relevant tags to your question.

Comment: Remove e.preventDefault() function. You can use Partial View instead.

Comment: @RohanRao it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed by doing the following:

Add `data-dismiss="modal"` in the button to add:

```
<div class="col-md-5">
    <input type="button" value="Add" class="btn btn-primary"  data-dismiss="modal" id="btnAddAttendance"/>
</div>
```

And also remove `$('#attnModal').modal().hide();`:

```
if (res.Status) {
    //$('#attnModal').modal().hide();
    $('#btnReload').click();
}
else {
    OpenAlertPopup("Attendance", res.ErrorMessage);
    //$('#attnModal').modal().hide();
}
```